# Matlab GUI callback troubles

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I try to make the uipanel change boarder colors while pressing and releasing mouse button on elsewhere except inputs and panel buttons.

```
function    [oldpropvalues,varargout]=DisableFigure(handlearray,prop,propvalue,varargin);

  oldpropvalues=get(handlearray,prop);

  %this IF is used to highlight the "modal" panel when anywhere outside it is pressed

  if length(varargin)==2  

    %these two are the old windowbutton functions which will be put back when the window is put back to normal.
    varargout{1}=get(varargin{1},'windowbuttondownfcn');    
    varargout{2}=get(varargin{1},'windowbuttonupfcn');

    set(varargin{1},'windowbuttondownfcn',['set(varargin{2},''bordertype'',''line'',''borderwidth'',2,''highlightcolor'',[0 0 0])']);
    set(varargin{1},'windowbuttonupfcn',['set(varargin{2},''bordertype'',''beveledout'',''borderwidth'',1,''highlightcolor'',[1 1 1])']);

  end 

  set(handlearray,prop,propvalue);
```

The error shows
 Undefined variable "varargin" or class "varargin".

Error while evaluating Figure WindowButtonDownFcn

Undefined variable "varargin" or class "varargin".

Error while evaluating Figure WindowButtonUpFcn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're defining your [window callbacks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_d0e275406) as character vectors, which are evaluated in the base workspace where the variable `varargin` doesn't exist. You can define them as [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) instead:

```
set(varargin{1}, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', ...
    @(~, ~) set(varargin{2}, 'BorderType', 'line', 'BorderWidth', 2, ...
                'HighlightColor', [0 0 0]));
set(varargin{1}, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', ...
    @(~, ~) set(varargin{2}, 'BorderType', 'beveledout', 'BorderWidth', 1, ...
                'HighlightColor', [1 1 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not show how you produced the error, but from the error message, I guess you called the function with less than 4 input arguments. Then `varargin` does not exist, so matlab gives the error.

To avoid the error, you need to check `nargin` before you use `varargin`, for example, replace your `if` statement line with

```
if nargin==5 % so length(varargin)==2
```

Comment: This is where I call the function [vabls.PatchFunctions, vabls.WindowFunctionA, vabls.WindowFunctionB]=DisableFigure(vabls.PatchHandles,''buttondownfcn'','''',guiele.CONTWIND,guiele.PolyEditPanel);

Comment: My varargin are the figure and uipanel.